# Как сделать чтобы после создания одной картинки, в объекте создавалась другая с уменьшенным размером?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Стоит задача. Нужно придумать чтобы при создании объекта модели и при добавлении в объект картинки, чтобы в этом же объекте автоматически создавался вторая картинка(возможно для этого нужно отдельное поле) с уменьшенным разрешением. Не знаю даже где бы посмотреть о таком и почитать. Есть у кого идеи?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться зачем хранить одно изображение в двух разрешениях?

Comment: Одно изображение для обложки новости, другое для баннера новости. Должно это все быть сделано через бэк и пользователь должен загружать всего одну картинку.

Comment: Одну картинку, то есть загрузить и чтобы она сама изменила размер, но исходная большая картинка осталась.

Comment: https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail . Она позволяет при создании respose приводить картинку к нужному виду. Для апи есть сериализатор https://github.com/dessibelle/sorl-thumbnail-serializer-field

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться